# How to cope with Google API asynchronous behavior?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have a simple Android app. The main activity looks for a file on the internal device storage. What happens after that depends on whether the file exists or not. This sequence works just fine as the whole execution is synchronous.

If I now use Google Drive API, all file access are asynchronous and the main activity goes on without waiting for the result of my search...

I found no way to 'force' a synchronous behavior. Synchronous calls of Google API are not allowed in the UI thread.
Moreover, performing such calls in an AsyncTask leads to the same problem...

Any idea on how to handle such scenarios ?

Regards,

Laurent

------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------

I tried several options but they all lead to the same result.
Both the main activity and the asynctask used to look for my file get blocked.
Any idea why and what to do ?
Main activity code :

```
if (!TermsOfUseAgreementHandler.mTermsOfUseAgreed) {
    Log.i(mTag, "Terms of use agreement needs to be checked");
    mCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    TermsOfUseAgreementSearchTask searchAgreementTask = new TermsOfUseAgreementHandler().new TermsOfUseAgreementSearchTask();
    // Start the async task to look for agreement file using parallel execution
    searchAgreementTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    try {
        // Block the main thread so that the task gets a chance to perform its Google Drive access...
        mCountDownLatch.await(); // MAIN ACTIVITY HANGS HERE !
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(mTag, "Failed to look for user agreement file", e);
    }
    // The async task should have finished (and decreased mCountDownLatch so that await returns)
    // At this moment, the result should be available for the main activity in mTermsOfUseAgreed...
    if (!TermsOfUseAgreementHandler.mTermsOfUseAgreed)
        TermsOfUseAgreementHandler.checkTermsOfUse(this);
}
```

AsyncTask code :

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Looking for user agreement file");
    // Look for the agreement file with synchronous Google Drive API access
    Query lookForAgreement = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, mTermsOfUseAgreementFile)).build();
    MetadataBuffer result = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient).queryChildren(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, lookForAgreement).await().getMetadataBuffer(); // ASYNCTASK HANGS HERE !
    mTermsOfUseAgreed = result != null
        && result.getCount() != 0
        && result.get(0) != null
        && result.get(0).getTitle() != null
        && result.get(0).getTitle().equals(mTermsOfUseAgreementFile);
    // Now that the result is available, decrease the countDownLatch so that the main activity may continue...
    MainActivity.mCountDownLatch.countDown();
    return mTermsOfUseAgreed;
}
```

------------------------- EDIT 2 ----------------------------------

I also tried to move the connection to the drive API from the main activity to the asynctask as shown in a drive API example [link](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ApiClientAsyncTask.java).
I still get the same result but the problem is now the connection because the associated callback listener is never called...

```
public class TermsOfUseAgreementSearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
    final private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public TermsOfUseAgreementSearchTask(Context context) {
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
        mClient = builder.build();
        mClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Connected");
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {}
        });
        mClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Connection failed");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Connect to drive API");
        mClient.connect();
        try {
            Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Wait for connection");
            latch.await(); // ASYNC TASK HANGS HERE !
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!mClient.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Log.i(MainActivity.mTag, "Looking for user agreement file");
            // Look for the agreement file with synchronous Google Drive API access
            Query lookForAgreement = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, mTermsOfUseAgreementFile)).build();
            MetadataBuffer result = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mClient).queryChildren(mClient, lookForAgreement).await().getMetadataBuffer();
            mTermsOfUseAgreed = result != null
                    && result.getCount() != 0
                    && result.get(0) != null
                    && result.get(0).getTitle() != null
                    && result.get(0).getTitle().equals(mTermsOfUseAgreementFile);
            // Now that the result is available, decrease the countDownLatch so that the main activity may continue...
            //MainActivity.mCountDownLatch.countDown();
            return mTermsOfUseAgreed;
        } finally {
            mClient.disconnect();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: can you confirm if you are using the Drive API or the Drive Android API?

Comment: I'm using the 'Google Drive Android API' : [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)